# Phonegap 1.2 not work on iPhone 3G iOS 3.x

Tags: iphone, crash, cordova, 3g

Xcode 4. I tried this fix: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/221 but still every PhoneGap 1.x application is crash on jailbreaked iPhone 3G.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread can be useful:

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8fea7c47fbfa8ae0

Good Luck!